# jQuery: add PHP with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have simple jQuery code where Im trying to like in PHP echo in jQuery to my website. But when I do it like this:

```
$( ".doc-list" ).html( "include 'documents.php';" );
```

My code echo it on site like:

```
include 'documents.php';
```

So my problem is when I make code like upwards jQuery echo it like plain text not like PHP and I need to include to my index.php documents.php when AJAX is done.

Answer (score 0):

To load data from server use `.load()`:

```
$( ".doc-list" ).load( "documents.php" );
```

Also, learn about client side and server side differences. Javascript (client-side) does not know anything about php code or any other code on your server side. Helpful question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming).

Comment: but I need only add to index.php include 'documents.php'; with JavaScript or jQuery ...